# Get missing dates of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the next dictionary and I need to get the missing periods between the determinate period, in other words, get the period between the end date of one period and the start date of the next one.

```
{'0': {'enddate': u'2017/05/25',
       'startdate': u'2017/05/01'},
 '1': {'enddate': u'2017/09/30',
       'startdate': u'2017/06/01'},
 '2': {'enddate': u'2018/03/31',
       'startdate': u'2018/01/01'},
 '3': {'enddate': u'2019/02/28',
       'startdate': u'2018/05/01'}}
```

I dont know exactly how can i store the missing dates.. I guess the best option to store it is in another dictionary maybe.. So i need another dict, based in the example i posted, like this:

```
{'0': {'enddate': u'2017/05/26',
       'startdate': u'2017/05/31'},
 '1': {'enddate': u'2017/12/31',
       'startdate': u'2017/10/01'},
 '2': {'enddate': u'2019/03/30',
       'startdate': u'2018/04/01'}'
```

The function to get this dict is simple:

```
def periods(periods):

    total_periods={}
    for period in periods:
        total_periods[period] = {}
        for  startdate in periods[period][0]:
            total_periods[period]['startdate'] = startdate
        for enddate in periods[period][-1]:
            total_periods[period]['enddate'] = enddate
```

The input of this function is another function who recolect all dates in a directory's tree.
The issue is that I don't know how to do it exactly, I tried different options that I found here but with no success... I would appreciate any help or guideline to start...
Hope I explain correctly and clearly.

Best regards.

Comment: What's the issue exactly?

Comment: The issue is that i dont know how to do it exactly, i tried differents options that i found here but with no success... I would appreciate any help or guideline to start..

Comment: Are you forced to use the input dict or you can use another data structure?

Comment: @balderman i preffer a dictionay or an array.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with just one `for` loop:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
result = {}

for k,v in d.items():  # d is your input times
    n= str(int(k)+1) 
    if n in d: 
        result[f'{k}-{n}'] = {'start':datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(d[k]['enddate'], '%Y/%m/%d')+timedelta(days=1),'%Y/%m/%d'), 'end':datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(d[n]['startdate'], '%Y/%m/%d')-timedelta(days=1),'%Y/%m/%d')}
```

the result will be:

```
{'0-1': {'start': '2017/05/26', 'end': '2017/05/31'},
 '1-2': {'start': '2017/10/01', 'end': '2017/12/31'},
 '2-3': {'start': '2018/04/01', 'end': '2018/04/30'}}
```

if you are not using `Python3.6` or higher change `f'{k}-{n}'` to `'{}-{}'.format(k,n)`.

Comment: your python version ? @hmar

Answer (score 0):

Some rough ideas:

1. Parse dates using `datetime.strptime`
2. In a dict store the parsed `start_date` as key and the difference between `end_date` and `start_date` as value (the later is a `datetime.timedelta` object)
3. Do a list with the keys in order and see if there is a gap.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import datetime
import pprint

data = {'0': {'enddate': u'2017/05/25',
              'startdate': u'2017/05/01'},
        '1': {'enddate': u'2017/09/30',
              'startdate': u'2017/06/01'},
        '2': {'enddate': u'2018/03/31',
              'startdate': u'2018/01/01'},
        '3': {'enddate': u'2019/02/28',
              'startdate': u'2018/05/01'}}

start = 1
output = dict()
while True:
    entry_1 = data.get(str(start - 1), None)
    entry_2 = data.get(str(start), None)
    if entry_1 is None or entry_2 is None:
        break
    else:
        start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(entry_2['startdate'], '%Y/%M/%d')
        end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(entry_1['enddate'], '%Y/%M/%d')
        output['{}-{}'.format(start, start - 1)] = {'start': str(start_date), 'end': str(end_date),
                                                    'delta': str(end_date - start_date)}
        start += 1
pprint.pprint(output)
```

Output

```
{'1-0': {'delta': '23 days, 23:59:00',
         'end': '2017-01-25 00:05:00',
         'start': '2017-01-01 00:06:00'},
 '2-1': {'delta': '-336 days, 0:08:00',
         'end': '2017-01-30 00:09:00',
         'start': '2018-01-01 00:01:00'},
 '3-2': {'delta': '29 days, 23:58:00',
         'end': '2018-01-31 00:03:00',
         'start': '2018-01-01 00:05:00'}}
```

Comment: Hi, how can i remove the time? I only need the dates, and i want to remove the first key also 1-0, 2-1, 3-2.. Thanks!